# Issue with XSL transform on XML due to 'alone' xmlns attribute within nested XML tag

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xml-namespaces

### Attempt the First

I have a page that is retrieving a response from a web service via SOAP. I am attempting to apply an XSL transform to the response, however, I am running into an issue because a nested tag contains a sole 'xmlns' attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetPartA xmlns="http://obfuscated.url.com/">
            <GetPartB>
                <Status>Ok</Status>
            </GetPartB>
        </GetPartA >
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

From what I gathered online, the solution involves declaring the namespace in the xsl file, and using this namespace to exact the selection, as an element containing the xmlns tag is not the same as one without. This is fine, but it's still not working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:np="http://obfuscated.url.com/"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/np:GetPartA/GetPartB/Status"/>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

#### Debug info

The following combination works, to pinpoint the problem more precisely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetPartA>
            <GetPartB>
                <Status>Ok</Status>
            </GetPartB>
        </GetPartA >
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note above, that <GetPartA> has been modified from  <GetPartA xmlns="http://obfuscated.url.com/">.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetPartA/GetPartB/Status"/>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4):

When you do this...

```
 <GetPartA xmlns="http://obfuscated.url.com/">
```

Then this declares a default namespace, so `GetPartA` and all its descendants are in this namespace. With namespaces, the prefix used (or lack of prefix in this case) is not the crucial factor, it is the namespace uri ("http://obfuscated.url.com/" in this case), that needs to match between XML and XSLT. The prefix used can be different though.

You are not actually far off in your first attempt though. You just need to use the `np` before `GetPartB` and `Status` in your XPath expression too.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:np="http://obfuscated.url.com/"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/np:GetPartA/np:GetPartB/np:Status"/>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That did it, thank you, and thanks for the concise explanation!